# What is a "field action", and how does it relate to group actions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, group-actions

If $G$ is a group and $X$ is a set (possibly with some extra structure defined on it), then a *group action of $G$ on $X$* is a map $a:G\times X\to X$ such that

- $a(1,x)=x$
- $a(g,a(h,x))=a(gh,x)$

Now, a vector space is often described as a *field* acting on an abelian group. The "acting" part of this description seems to refer to the following four axioms:

1. $\lambda(u+v)=\lambda u+\lambda v$
2. $(\lambda + \mu)v=\lambda v+\mu v$
3. $1v=v$
4. $(\lambda \mu )v=\lambda(\mu v)$

My question is twofold: is there a precise notion of a "field action" on some algebraic structure, and if so, how does it relate to group actions?

Of course, axioms (3) and (4) of a vector space bear a lot of resemblance to the axioms of a group action. Axiom (3) states that the identity element behaves in the way you expect it to, and axiom (4) is a kind of "associativity". But I wonder if the connection between these two types of "action" runs deeper than this.

Comment: More generally, you can define a module over a ring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)

Comment: @morrowmh: I suppose then that my question could equally be phrased as "How does the way a ring acts on an abelian group resemble the way a group acts on a particular structure"? Perhaps there is nothing "special" about fields here.

Comment: Informally "an action of $\mathcal{A}$ on $\mathcal{B}$" should be a map $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ that "respects the structure" of both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. But I *don't* think there is, or should be, a single formal notion of what this means. For example, let's say we look at an algebra over a field as an example of a field action on a ring. Then we have as part of our "field-acting-on-ring" rules that $$\lambda(a+b)=\lambda a+\lambda b$$ but$$\lambda (a\cdot b)=(\lambda a)\cdot b=a\cdot (\lambda b)$$ $({\color{red}{\not=}}(\lambda a)\cdot(\lambda b))$.

Comment: So there isn't a generally-applicable rule of "how actions play with binary operations" - rather, we need to look at what the binary operations in question *mean*, and what we want our actions do capture. I'm not aware offhand of instances where two incompatible notions of action are each interesting, but I wouldn't be surprised to find that such exist.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Sorry for the late reply. It seems evident then that there isn't one notion of an algebraic structure acting on another. But could it be that we *can* formalise the notion of "action" in a general way – it's just that there are many different possible formalisations. Or can we only formally make sense of "actions" when we specialise to particular algebraic structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An action of a monoid $M$ on a set $X$ is a monoid homomorphism $M\to\mathrm{End}(X)$.
This makes sense because
$$\mathrm{End}(X)=\{\text{functions } f:X\to X\}$$
is a monoid. If $M$ is a group, then an action of $M$ on $X$ is a group action.

Similarly, an action of a ring $R$ on an Abelian group $A$ is a ring homomorphism $R\to\mathrm{End}(A)$, where now
$$\mathrm{End}(A)=\{\text{group homomorphisms } f:A\to A\}$$
is a ring. If $R$ is a field, then an action of $R$ on $A$ is a field action.